# Is this exercise about the order of an element in an abelian group incorrectly stated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm trying to do **Exercise 2.2.6** from textbook *Groups, Matrices, and Vector Spaces - A Group Theoretic Approach to Linear Algebra* by James B. Carrell.

> [image]

I suspect that it is incorrectly stated because on other links, the problem is stated as

> if $G$ is an Abelian group with elements $a$ and $b$ with orders $m$ and $n$, respectively, then $G$ contains an element whose order is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Could you please confirm if my observation is correct?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. For example, suppose $x$ and $y$ are inverses of each order, both of order $n$.

Comment: @verret Please post your comment as an answer!

Comment: The result is incorrect as stated. It is correct under some mild assumptions, e..g, of for every prime $p$ that divides the $\gcd$, the highest power of $p$ that divides $m$ is different from the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$; or if $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle$ is trivial.

Comment: Another way to make the exercise correct is to weaken the conclusion to: The order of $xy$ divides the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$. (I suspect that this is what the author had in mind when writing the incorrect version.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass did you mean that the order of $xy$ is a divisor of $\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @Arturo Magidin's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list. All credits are given to @Arturo Magidin.

> The result is incorrect as stated. It is correct under some mild assumptions, e..g, of for every prime $p$ that divides the $\gcd$, the highest power of $p$ that divides $m$ is different from the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$; or if $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle$ is trivial.